# 'toLowerCase' of undefined error in canMerge.js for css loading

Tags: css, angular, metronic

Getting a weird error on `ng serve`

```
styles.css - Error: styles.css from Css Minimizer
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
at /Users/pavlos-mac/projects/internal_portal/internal_portal/styles.css:73837:1
```

`node.value` is `undefined` in `canMerge.js` which is part of the css loading.

```
const hasInherit = node => node.value.toLowerCase() === 'inherit';
```

Any ideas?